Plotting a surface over lines plotly
I have this code snipped, that should plot a surface over a few lines:
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import math
import numpy as np

t_changes = np.linspace((0.005*2*math.pi)/60 , (1*2*math.pi)/60 , 10)

omega_all = np.linspace((1*2*math.pi)/60  ,(12*2*math.pi)/60 , 10)

max_values_all = [1.4185558393536863, 1.4325906947905434, 1.438658017942095, 1.4806644284478363, 1.4761508670671415, 1.4649492471829895, 1.464546919691028, 1.4578007061068432, 1.4428714932707587, 1.4500144702965356],[1.6441629388568684, 1.642323391267553, 1.6491736867101752, 1.6412988007431675, 1.6290382708032518, 1.687033971399921, 1.7249970205847203, 1.7375113332368095, 1.734492370556642, 1.7242648069286037],[2.0845437496335575, 2.072843683096361, 2.035169117911497, 2.063686038710132, 1.966491883139673, 2.036435788844538, 2.000384950132592, 1.9602627462709168, 1.9992717869448466, 2.02862099663119],[3.3253818185735087, 3.1215539630481604, 2.981889203258018, 2.8546336239840215, 2.7042612422101002, 2.575780911605224, 2.5755048740741917, 2.6205430458363095, 2.576086019821094, 2.487398700065042],[15.432838261722877, 6.5095720712941985, 5.200282346853118, 4.495357558732455, 4.136530871191216, 3.766634997051916, 3.6827888643956186, 3.4764385554542914, 3.430120257752737, 3.4201713261825426],[75.66433489618231, 15.94566966995464, 10.161220922127605, 8.007523032946853, 6.800634588849489, 6.000935050965966, 5.536898133810305, 5.21365607068837, 5.010566351336815, 4.708208983726101],[75.66286832418304, 15.363231967657855, 15.81080564424909, 13.0105751921456, 11.001714824633169, 9.553264617238883, 8.572992551192133, 8.004222045653602, 7.365317024063387, 7.085229662879642],[75.66242236630372, 15.363226081588929, 10.955988755682252, 13.158249063867139, 14.179122828320526, 13.460821531609223, 12.624633192306533, 11.937231489633758, 11.274180241228226, 10.672516546418693],[75.65799160190585, 21.62711751806979, 18.008379194730093, 14.53079025616018, 8.520673195597784, 14.016979085011064, 16.276408102947748, 17.05937073631494, 17.220381393056392, 16.8222819511244],[118.96662233164312, 66.31352570490306, 68.16962905085047, 61.396954421293266, 74.95559072827379, 67.92902322683065, 63.00643530404031, 63.21829273940191, 65.26976962802642, 67.46680681352494]
fig = go.Figure()

# Loop through each line and add it to the figure
for i in range(len(omega_all)):
    x_vals = [omega_all[i]*60/(2*math.pi)]* len(t_changes)
    y_vals = t_changes
    z_vals = max_values_all[i]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x_vals, y=y_vals, z=z_vals, mode='lines'))


fig.add_trace(go.Surface(x=(omega_all*60/(2*math.pi)), y=t_changes, z=max_values_all))
# Set layout
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(aspectmode="cube"))

# Show the figure
fig.show()

But the result is this:

I don't get why, maybe you can help.
As you can see the lines are plotted just fine but the surface is on the wrong side and not very accuratly tracing the lines in my opinion.

Interesting question - it looks like the go.Surface is using different axes from the Scatter3d, but I don't know how to fix it. If you don't get an answer here, you may be able to get one from https://community.plotly.com/

@Mo711, could you perhaps provide (dummy) values for the variables omega_all, t_changes and max_values_all?

@UnicornOnAzur I have made the code executable, so you can try it yourself

Please check this one?
We just need to create the list & put the value in it
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import math
import numpy as np

t_changes = np.linspace((0.005*2*math.pi)/60 , (1*2*math.pi)/60 , 10)

omega_all = np.linspace((1*2*math.pi)/60  ,(12*2*math.pi)/60 , 10)

max_values_all = [1.4185558393536863, 1.4325906947905434, 1.438658017942095, 1.4806644284478363, 1.4761508670671415, 1.4649492471829895, 1.464546919691028, 1.4578007061068432, 1.4428714932707587, 1.4500144702965356],[1.6441629388568684, 1.642323391267553, 1.6491736867101752, 1.6412988007431675, 1.6290382708032518, 1.687033971399921, 1.7249970205847203, 1.7375113332368095, 1.734492370556642, 1.7242648069286037],[2.0845437496335575, 2.072843683096361, 2.035169117911497, 2.063686038710132, 1.966491883139673, 2.036435788844538, 2.000384950132592, 1.9602627462709168, 1.9992717869448466, 2.02862099663119],[3.3253818185735087, 3.1215539630481604, 2.981889203258018, 2.8546336239840215, 2.7042612422101002, 2.575780911605224, 2.5755048740741917, 2.6205430458363095, 2.576086019821094, 2.487398700065042],[15.432838261722877, 6.5095720712941985, 5.200282346853118, 4.495357558732455, 4.136530871191216, 3.766634997051916, 3.6827888643956186, 3.4764385554542914, 3.430120257752737, 3.4201713261825426],[75.66433489618231, 15.94566966995464, 10.161220922127605, 8.007523032946853, 6.800634588849489, 6.000935050965966, 5.536898133810305, 5.21365607068837, 5.010566351336815, 4.708208983726101],[75.66286832418304, 15.363231967657855, 15.81080564424909, 13.0105751921456, 11.001714824633169, 9.553264617238883, 8.572992551192133, 8.004222045653602, 7.365317024063387, 7.085229662879642],[75.66242236630372, 15.363226081588929, 10.955988755682252, 13.158249063867139, 14.179122828320526, 13.460821531609223, 12.624633192306533, 11.937231489633758, 11.274180241228226, 10.672516546418693],[75.65799160190585, 21.62711751806979, 18.008379194730093, 14.53079025616018, 8.520673195597784, 14.016979085011064, 16.276408102947748, 17.05937073631494, 17.220381393056392, 16.8222819511244],[118.96662233164312, 66.31352570490306, 68.16962905085047, 61.396954421293266, 74.95559072827379, 67.92902322683065, 63.00643530404031, 63.21829273940191, 65.26976962802642, 67.46680681352494]
fig = go.Figure()

lx = []
ly = []
lz = []
# Loop through each line and add it to the figure
for i in range(len(omega_all)):
    x_vals = [omega_all[i]*60/(2*math.pi)]* len(t_changes)
    y_vals = t_changes
    z_vals = max_values_all[i]
    lx.append(x_vals)
    ly.append(y_vals)
    lz.append(z_vals)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter3d(x=x_vals, y=y_vals, z=z_vals, mode='lines'))


fig.add_trace(go.Surface(x=lx, y=ly, z=lz))
# Set layout
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(aspectmode="cube"))

# Show the figure
fig.show()

Here is the result

Also, the problem is came from the max_values_all is a tuple of lists, not a list like the t_changes & omega_all
